# How to make it have a picture and the text will automatically change according to the picture

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

on my wp page https://www.mycasinohub.sk I have a section (see picture) where I have an image slider and on the left I have a text which that does not change. **How to make the text change when I swipe an image.** There are **8 images** and I want to upload **8 different texts** there.

Screen : https://ibb.co/mcNry8w

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would start off by checking out [mcve].

Comment: How did you make this slider? Did you use plugin?

Comment: If its wordpress, there are a lot of plugins that can do what you need.